# Exporting data from RDS SQL

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I'm trying to get my data out of a SQL Server RDS instance, but I'm having a lot of difficulty, mainly due to users and logins.

I've tried using the Tasks > Generate Scripts, but this gives me errors when trying to create the database at the other end.

I've tried using SQLAzureMW - this was amazing for getting data in to the RDS instance, but the command line app gives me errors when trying to connect to the remote RDS instance

I've tried Tasks > Copy Database, but I get error saying EXECUTE permission was denied on object 'xp_regread'

I've tried Tasks > Export Data wizard, but it just copies data and drops all of my triggers and keys

I've been searching all afternoon and I can't find any references to this issue at all. Am I missing something really obvious here? Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: For clarification, are you trying to get just the data (or even just a table or two worth of data) or are you looking to "export" the database as a whole? It sounds more like the latter.

Comment: I'm trying to get the entire database to create an offsite copy.
In the end, I used Generate Scripts to transfer the schema, then I had to add non-default roles and user mappings manually.
Then I used SQLAzureMW to transfer the data only.
This kind of works, but obviously it's not an ideal solution, so I would still appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!